# LinearLayout with percent empty space

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I am working on linear layout for my simple android application. I wanna make the portion of two views dynamically change based on the size ( **I want to have, for a row for left to right, the first 20% is empty, and all the content is inside the rest of 80%)** . For this approach, i chosen the weight for different view. I created an nested linear layout for this approach. For example, the layout hierarchy is something like this.

```
<linearLayout> //parent layout
   <linearLayout //child 1 layout
        android:layout_weight="1"> 
        //so that this view occupy 20% of the space regardless the width of device. I intensionally wanna keep this view empty. 
   </linearLayout>
   <linearLayout //child 2 layout
         android:layout_weight="4">
          //so that this view occupy 80% of the space regardless the width of device. and 
          //inside this view I have whatever view I wanna add on it. 
      <EditText>
      <ImageView>
   </linearLayout>
</linearLayout>
```

With this approach, the Lint in Android Studio tell me the following warnings:

1. This is a Nested Layout. Layout weights require a widget to be measured twice.    When a LinearLayout with non-zero weights is nested inside another LinearLayout with non-zero weights, then the number of measurements increase exponentially.
2. the **child 1 layout** is useless: This `LinearLayout` view is useless (no children, no `background`, no `id`, no `style`)

Can anyone address me the right layout  to use in order to have the layout dynamically change based on the size of devices? How should I correctly set up the empty space for a linear layout case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a possible solution using weights:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <!-- Your content here: -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:layout_gravity="end" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is exactly what i am looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`PercentRelativeLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html).

Note: You need the [Percent library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#percent) to use it.